# Setup multiple WordPress domains one single server. (Nginx)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I've recently set-up one website domain with WordPress on my server.
And I have repeated the steps, with a separate installation, for another domain name. To create a separate site with WordPress.
However, the new WordPress installation seems to be redirecting to the first WordPress content (not the theme) and Admin panel.

How can I really make it separate from the first one, so I can start building another WordPress site?

All the info I can find is about subdomains and stuff, but that is not what I am looking for.

Edit:
I did make another DB and DB user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be posted on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, no offence, but there are multiple questions regarding WordPress on Stackoverflow. Would you comment the exact same thing on all of those questions too? ...But you are correct, and I will remember it for the next time. ;)

Comment: If they come up in the review queue I will.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my setup, probably in terms of directories, caused the issue somehow.

I follow this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps

Works perfectly fine right now.